# CPU Temperature and Fan Control

Tags: cpu, overheating, fan, temperature

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on my MSI GS63. With windows the thermals go high when I run a mode like Turbo but otherwise everything is fine. While running Ubuntu, the CPU temperature stays 60-70 degree Celsius on average without anything heavy running. When I run Gazebo, CPU stays at 70-90 degree celsius on average.

I have also noticed that only one fan runs out of the 3 on Ubuntu. It would be great if someone can tell me a workaround or guide me through getting all the fans running.

Comment: Have you tired adjusting the fan settings in your BIOS?

Comment: No I haven't. All 3 fans run on windows but only one on ubuntu. Should I try something in the BIOS?